# When I am reducing boolean statements, is there a specific order? How do I know when to stop?

Tags: java, boolean, logic

When reducing a statement like this:

```
!(n || p)|| p &&(n || q)
```

I look first at the NOT symbol, and reduce using De Morgan's law.

```
!n && !p || p &&(n || q)
```

At this point, it looks like this is as reduced as it can get.

I cannot use any laws on the `p &&(n || q)` part.

I cannot use any more laws on the `!n && !p` part.

Because AND comes before OR, I assume I cannot begin reducing other parts out of order, such as `!p || p` into True.

Can it be reduced more and I am just not seeing something?

Comment: Check out the order of operations in Java for help https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/

Comment: I just imagined seeing this in some real code, my I would have hated it... the question is good though

Comment: What do you optimize for? Do you want the most compact form?

Comment: See [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm), for instance.

Comment: @lexicore I teach computer science, and we have some worksheets where we need to reduce Boolean statements using the laws.  I cannot find the key, so I am doing them all by hand again.  I also have not done this in a year, so I am a bit rusty.

Comment: @MattJenkins Still, you need some optimization goals. Or is it just "apply these rules until none is applicable"?

Comment: @MattJenkins I am asking because some people might prefer a disjunctive form like `!n && !p || n && p || p && q` even if it is a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a specific algorithm for general reductions, but in this case there are other properties which can be used to reduce further:

1. This step is just a grouping by precedence:

   ```
   (!n && !p) || (p && (n || q))
   ```
2. Using distributivity:

   ```
   (!n && !p) || ((p && n) || (p && q))
   ```
3. Using associativity and commutativity:

   ```
   ((!n && !p) || (n && p)) || (p && q)
   ```
4. I don't know if there's a specific name for this, but `(!n && !p) || (n && p)` is equivalent to `n == p`:

   ```
   (n == p) || (p && q)
   ```

I solved this just by first noticing that `p` could be distributed which opened up other possibilities. Step 4 is a common identity, [mentioned here, for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equality#Alternative_descriptions), but I don't know if it has a name.

Here's a small program which shows that the truth tables really are the same:

```
class Example {
    static boolean f(boolean n, boolean p, boolean q) {
        return !(n || p) || p && (n || q);
    }
    static boolean g(boolean n, boolean p, boolean q) {
        return (n == p) || (p && q);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+-----+-----+");
        System.out.println("| n | p | q | f() | g() |");
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+-----+-----+");
        for (int i = 0b000; i <= 0b111; ++i) {
            boolean n = (i & 0b100) != 0;
            boolean p = (i & 0b010) != 0;
            boolean q = (i & 0b001) != 0;
            boolean f = f(n, p, q);
            boolean g = g(n, p, q);
            System.out.printf("| %s | %s | %s |  %s  |  %s  |%n",
                              ch(n), ch(p), ch(q), ch(f), ch(g));
        }
        System.out.println("+---+---+---+-----+-----+");
    }
    static char ch(boolean b) { return b ? 'T' : 'F'; }
}
```

And the truth tables:

```
+---+---+---+-----+-----+
| n | p | q | f() | g() |
+---+---+---+-----+-----+
| F | F | F |  T  |  T  |
| F | F | T |  T  |  T  |
| F | T | F |  F  |  F  |
| F | T | T |  T  |  T  |
| T | F | F |  F  |  F  |
| T | F | T |  F  |  F  |
| T | T | F |  T  |  T  |
| T | T | T |  T  |  T  |
+---+---+---+-----+-----+
```